# Python: Mock a instance variable with a side_effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

we currently try to mock an instance variable of a class object with a side_effect. The first time we access the attribute we want to get a different value as the second time. We test an async method and the value can change during the two accesses.

Here is a simple example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import PropertyMock, patch


class MyObject:

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = None

    def my_func(self):
        print(self.variable)
        print(self.variable)


class TestObject(TestCase):

    def test_my_func(self):
        object = MyObject()
        with patch.object(object, "variable", new_callable=PropertyMock(side_effect=["test", "test2"])):
            object.my_func()
```

We would expect that this print at first test and then test2.
But the output is:

```
test
test
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Comment: Why do you need the value of the `variable` attribute to change between two calls to `my_func`? Depending on the answer to that question, I'd suggest making `__init__` take an argument (which a default value of `None`) to set `self.variable`, then simply creating two separate instances `MyObject("test")` and `MyObject("test2")` to use in your test.

Comment: If that's not feasible, I suggest providing a definition of `MyObject` that more closely matches your real class.

Comment: I changed the example a little bit. I must change the property during a method call. It's an async application and the value can change during the method call

Comment: I would work on mocking/stubbing whatever external resource could change the attribute's value, rather than changing the value directly. Otherwise, you aren't really testing your code, you're just hacking the code to conform to your test.

Comment: sounds like a design flaw in your tests to be honest

Comment: For example, if you wanted to check the value of `self.variable` before and after `self.variable = foo()`, you wouldn't mock the attribute; you'd mock `foo` to return the new value and let your code assign `self.variable` normally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify your use-case with something like this:-

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__var = 0

    @property
    def var(self):
        rv = self.__var
        self.__var += 1
        return rv


MC = MyClass()
print(MC.var)
print(MC.var)
```

Every time MC.var is acquired using this technique it will be incremented by 1. Obviously a variation on your theme but may give you some ideas